# ExtJS 4 Naming Conventions

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I was discussing with my colleagues the correct naming conventions for classes, variables and objects etc within ExtJS 4, but we all had differing views.

Is there an "official" stance on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently attended an Ext.js 4 training course (delivered by Sencha) and their advice was the following:

- Top-level namespaces and the actual class names should be Camel Cased. everything else should be in lowercase.
- Acronyms should also be camel cased
- Do not use underscores, hyphens an any other non-alphanumerical characters

So Hugh is pretty much on the money

Answer (score 8):

There absolutely is an official stance. It is outline in section 2 of the Class System guide. Here is the link: [https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/core_concepts/classes.html#core_concepts-*-classes*-_naming_conventions](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/core_concepts/classes.html#core_concepts-_-classes_-_naming_conventions)

Answer (score 7):

Official, I'm not sure, but in my opinion..

- Root namespaces and constructors are `UpperCamelCase`
- Sub-namespaces, styles, events and xtypes are `lowercase`
- Methods, attributes and variables are `lowerCamelCase`

Answer (score 3):

It's preference, really. What Hugh said are good guidelines, but I actually prefer namespaces to be in ALL CAPS, but our apps have fairly short namespaces so it doesn't look ridiculous.